# Is full text search not working any more?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, search

Just recently I was looking for some questions with a particular word in the title or the main text, but search no longer seems to find them.  For example searching for the word "gender" yields nothing, yet there are 84 hits from Google of questions containing that word.  This used to work as far as I can remember.  Having this ability is really important for finding duplicate questions, for example.

What's going on?

Comment: same with `metapost [tikz-pgf]`search it misses completely the hobby answers.

Comment: Hendrik Vogt didn’t hesitate: [meta.stackoverflow.com: *Search doesn't work as expected, neither does the “Related” bar*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170636)

Comment: This is also true for other type of search: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13304+[highlighting]+is%3Aanswer gives an empty set.

Comment: I do not think, it would be useful to add dozens of other examples, but here is an impressive one: Searching for mentions of the phrase "coffee stains" in questions (I could remember I had read at least one before; I aimed to link to one of them) http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22coffee+stains%22+is%3Aquestion does find nothing, not even http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=coffee does find one of these questions. With https://www.google.de/#q=%22coffee+stains%22+site:tex.stackexchange.com the first two results are the ones I wanted to have.

Comment: This seems to have been corrected?

Comment: @Werner: It appears so, yes - but no official reaction so far.

Comment: @Speravir: Can you please also check?

Comment: @Werner yes it appears to be fixed.

Comment: @HendrikVogt It appears the search is as bad as before. ;) Do you want to update the meta.so question, too? Anyway, an official reason/reaction would be interesting to read.

Comment: @HendrikVogt The first link in my comment above (repeated: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22coffee+stains%22+is%3Aquestion ) should find (at least) 2 questions, but does find only one – what nonetheless is a great achievement in relation to the situation some days ago.

Comment: @Speravir: Omit the `""`, then it finds both - not 100% sure why.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I wanted to wait a bit before updating yet again. Why do you say it's as bad as before? Do you mean "still bad, but less bad"?

Comment: @HendrikVogt When you say this, comes in my mind, that this happened to me already in another case, but I forgot later. This is clearly a bug, because it is an explained possibility in the “Advanced Search Tips”.

Comment: @Speravir: You're right, and thanks for pointing it out at Meta.SO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an oddity with the stem parser on a few indexes a few weeks ago.  This has since been corrected and results should be back to normal.